Generic configuration for setting up any reverse proxy, such as Traefik, Nginx or etc
Could someone assist me in obtaining the generic configuration required to set up any reverse proxy?
I attempted to explore a few online documents but didn't find much on this topic. If anyone has experience working in this area, their guidance would be appreciated.

do you want to configure reverse proxy in Nginx ?

Hi there! Have you followed these documents? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ If so, try starting there and then posting specific problems you are having. Server Fault is probably a better site for this question. See this for example: https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy
